# Convergence of sum of expectations

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent random variables with finite expectation.
If $\sum_{i=0}^\infty Var(X_i) < \infty$, Show that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty(X_i-E[X_i])$ converges almost surely.

$E[X_i]$ means a expectation of $X_i$

How to solve it? Use Weak Law of large numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Since you aim to show convergence almost surely, it will be an application of the strong law of large numbers. 
Therefore just define $Y_i = X_i -\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ and it remains to verify, that the $Y_i$ are uncorrelated, have the same expectation (both clear) and $\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2] < \infty$ and have bounded variance (both given due to the finiteness of the series).

Comment: Law of large numbers is not applicable because the $X_i$'s are not identically distributed?

Answer (score 0):

Law of large numbers is not applicable because the $X_i$'s are not identically distributed.

Step 1: Suppose on the contrary that $$P(\sum_{i=0}^\infty(X_i-E[X_i]) = \infty) > 0$$

Step 2: Then

$$E[\sum_{i=0}^\infty(X_i-E[X_i])] = \infty$$

Step 3: By Fubini's Theorem, we have

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty E[(X_i-E[X_i])] = \infty$$

Step 4:

$$\to \sum_{i=0}^\infty 0 = \infty$$

Step 5:

$$\to 0 = \infty$$

QED

Some notes:

1. The variance is a red herring much like in the law of large numbers.
2. It is indeed possible that $P(\sum_k X_k = \infty)>0$ while $\sum_k Var(X_k) < \infty$. However, [if $E[X_k] = 0$, then $P(\sum_k X_k = \infty)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755255)

Comment: @BCLN this argument is not Mathematics at all.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why? I just extended 'If $X= \infty$ then $E[X] = \infty$' to 'If $X= \infty$ for positive probability' and then Fubini's theorem doesn't require convergence...I think?

Answer (score 0):

This requires a few theorems. First of all, for a series of independent random variables all types of convergence (almost sure convergence, convergence in prbability, convergence in distribution, convergence in $L^{p}$ in the special case when the p-th absolute moments exist)  are equivalent. Secondly convergence of the given series in $L^{2}$, i.e. in mean square is an elementary fact about convergence of a series in the norm of a Hilbert space when the terms are orthogonal.  From these two fact we get almost sure convergence.
Alternative proof: the partial sums of the series form a martingale. This martingale is $L^{2}$ bounded by hypothesis. By Martingale Convergence Theorem the series converges almost surely.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: In real Mathematics you cannot write $\sum a_n$ unless you know that the series is  convergent or diverges to $+\infty$ or diverges to $-\infty$. There are situations (like $\sum (-1)^{n}$) where none of  these is true.  @BCLC

Comment: i edited post. please state which particular step is wrong. you mean step 3 is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First note that by taking $Y_i = X_i - E[X_i]$, we assume that $E[X_i] = 0$.

Then, we use Kolmogorov's three-series theorem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem

Thus, it suffices to verify the three conditions. For any $A>0$,

(1) $$\sum^\infty_{n=1} P(|X_n > A|) \le \sum^\infty_{n=1} A^{-2}E[X_n^2] =\sum^\infty_{n=1} A^{-2}Var[X_n]  \le \infty $$

(2)  $$\sum^\infty_{n=1} E[X_n 1_{X_n\le A }] = - \sum^\infty_{n=1} E[X_n 1_{X_n> A }] ,$$

and
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1} |E[X_n 1_{X_n> A }]| \le \sum^\infty_{n=1} E[|X_n 1_{|X_n|> A }|] \le A^{-1} \sum^\infty_{n=1} E[|X_n^2 | ] < \infty,$$
which implies that $\sum^\infty_{n=1} E[X_n 1_{X_n\le A }]$ converges.

(3) Finally,  $$\sum^\infty_{n=1} |Var[X_n 1_{X_n\le A }] |\le \sum^\infty_{n=1} E[X_n^2 1_{X_n \le  A }] + (E[|X_n| 1_{X_n \le  A }] )^2 \le 2\sum^\infty_{n=1} E[X_n^2 ] < \infty,$$
where we used Holder's inequality for the second term in the last inequality.